# PDF contents are shifted to right and gets cut for wider page

Tags: android, pdf, itext

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pdfBtm, (int) (pdfBtm.getWidth()), (int) (pdfBtm.getHeight()), true);

bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);

byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Image img = Image.getInstance(byteArray);

String pdffile = sharedPref.getString(com.appealsoft.i_file_me.Config.PdffileName, ""); 
int pageNumber = sharedPref.getInt(com.appealsoft.i_file_me.Config.PdfpageNumber, 0);

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdffile);

String filename = pdffile.substring(pdffile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, pdffile.length());
System.out.println("file name is :" + filename);

OutputStream newfile  = new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/" + filename));
Document newDocs = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(newDocs, newfile);
newDocs.open();

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    if (i == pageNumber)
    {
        Image img2 = Image.getInstance(byteArray);
        newDocs.add(img2);

        System.out.println(" i was inside...");
    } else {
        Image img2 = Image.getInstance(writer.getImportedPage(reader, i));
        newDocs.add(img2);
    }
}
newDocs.close();
```

When I create PDF with this method, contents of PDF get shifted to right side. For wider PDF pages, some of the part of page gets cut.

Anyone know why this is so?

Comment: *Anyone know why this is so* - Because that is what your code tells iText to do: You take a complete page from some source document (including its margins) and add it to the stuff iText is arranging in the body of a new page which has its own margins. Your objective seems to be to replace a single page in some document. Use a PdfStamper or PdfCopy for that.

Comment: you are right sir.. i want to replace a particular page from pdf file. can you tell me how pdfCopy works, i tried stamper but didnt solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> When I create PDF with this method, contents of PDF get shifted to right side. For wider PDF pages, some of the part of page gets cut.
>
> Anyone know why this is so?

Because that is what the code tells iText to do: It takes a complete page from some source document (including its margins) and adds it to the stuff iText is arranging in the body of a new page which already has its own margins.

The OP's actual objective seems to be to replace a single page in some document with some image. A `PdfStamper` or `PdfCopy` instance should be used for that.

E.g. using `PdfStamper` you could do something like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
int pageToReplace = NROFPAGETOREPLACE;

List<Integer> pagesToKeep = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
    if (i != pageToReplace) pagesToKeep.add(i);

reader.selectPages(pagesToKeep);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(TARGET));

stamper.insertPage(pageToReplace, reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMAGESOURCE);
stamper.getOverContent(pageToReplace).addImage(image, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getHeight(), 30, 30);

stamper.close();
```

**PS:** Your comments seem to suggest that the image added to the new page actually encompasses all of it. In that case it is appropriate to replace the last lines of the example above with

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMAGESOURCE);
stamper.insertPage(pageToReplace, new Rectangle(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
stamper.getOverContent(pageToReplace).addImage(image, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getHeight(), 0, 0);

stamper.close();
```

Comment: PDFCopy is working fine for other pages.. but pages that i want to replace is still cuts. This may be because my bitmap is not properly converted into bytearray...

Comment: You'll have to adjust the parameters of the `addImage` call. E.g. the `30, 30` at the end cause a displacement by 30 units vertically and 30 units horizontally.

Comment: i tried it earlier sir.. but still have same issue.. is there anyway to view Pdf pages in android using iText. i am using PDFViwer but i think that is causing me issue. Is there anyway to view PDF pages as it is in android app.?

Comment: *i tried it earlier sir.. but still have same issue* - the code from my answer works for me, especially in combination with the hint *to adjust the parameters of the `addImage` call*. Please explain exactly what your issue is using that solution, otherwise I hardly can see how to help you. *i am using PDFViwer but i think that is causing me issue* - first verify your thinking by viewing the PDF in question on other viewers, e.g. Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Actually i want add signature in PDF page. If i open it with Acrobat reader then i cant apply actions to it. Not i am getting Bitmap of PDF page and adding signature image on it, and again from that bitmap creating PDF using iText. Now my created PDF is not properly aligned and cuts when PDF pages are wider though i used your solution .

Comment: So the image you want to add as a page actually encompasses the whole page? I added a **PS** to my answer for that case.

Comment: That been said... Why don't you simply add the signature image to the existing PDF using a `PdfStamper`?

Comment: i want user to add signarure where he wants. PDFstamper will add it in specified postion. Then how will i get user touch position as i can't view PDF with the help of iText.

Comment: Still issue exists. in short sir, i want implement add signature functionality provided by the Adobe reader into my application. Can i do that with PDFstamper od PDFCopy ?

Comment: *Still issue exists* - that is not possible... the added page now has the exact dimensions of the image put onto it, and it is added at the origin. If it still has additional space on the left or goes beyond some border, please share the PDFs for analysis.

Comment: how can i share it with you??

Comment: Unfortunately Stackoverflow does not allow sharing of non-image files. Thus, you have to share files via a file sharing service like google drive or drop box and post the URL here. Please don't use a file sharing service which drowns you in ads.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B8fVug4RUmgxaUNhbWFOQmNzMFE here are both the pdf.. original and singedPDF